# PostgreSQL: a query and a stored function based on the query return different numbers of records

Tags: postgresql, stored-functions

I have a query but since there are a lot of constants I decided to wrap this query in a stored function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_events_without_overlaping() 
   RETURNS event 
AS $$ 
    WITH RECURSIVE group_events AS (...) select * from group_event; $$ 
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

and pass this constants as parameters. When I ran this function I got one record, when I ran the query I got two records. How is it possible?

Comment: Probably your function has a wrong return type. Please, show the function.

Comment: Or read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23888675/postgres-function-returning-one-record-while-i-have-many-records

Comment: I have a table named event and I want my function returns event's records `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_events_without_overlaping() RETURNS event AS $$ WITH RECURSIVE group_events AS (...) select * from group_event; $$ LANGUAGE SQL`

Comment: Your function should return `SETOF event`. See the link above.

Comment: Thank you `SETOF event` really works, but I tried to create [this function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-TABLE-FUNCTIONS)

Comment: And they have one row as result :)

Comment: How do you _call_ the function?

Comment: Sounds like it should be a view, not a function, if it takes no parameters. Not a big deal, just cleaner.

Comment: Guys, thank you for your help, the statement SETOF helps me to solve this problem. I don't know how to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has to be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_events_without_overlaping() 
   RETURNS SET OF event 
AS $$ 
    WITH RECURSIVE group_events AS (...) select * from group_event; $$ 
LANGUAGE SQL;
```