# Postgres sql to print a variable in loop cycle

Tags: postgresql, function, printing

I need to print variable **i** in a loop cycle.
I use the following function:

```
csstress=>
csstress=> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "mgtest" () RETURNS integer AS
csstress-> $BODY$
csstress$> DECLARE
csstress$> i integer;
csstress$> BEGIN
csstress$> i := 0;
csstress$> FOR i IN 1..4 LOOP
csstress$> RAISE NOTICE 'Calling cs_create_job(%)', i;
csstress$> return i;
csstress$> END LOOP;
csstress$> END;
csstress$> $BODY$
csstress-> LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
CREATE FUNCTION
csstress=>
```

but when I call the function it prints only one, the first value

```
csstress=>
csstress=> select mgtest();
NOTICE:  Calling cs_create_job(1)
 mgtest
--------
      1
(1 row)

csstress=>
```

What do I do wrong? How to force the function to print something like

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Don't put the `return i;` **inside** the loop. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING for returning sets and sets of rows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Postgres function returning one record while I have many records?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23888675/postgres-function-returning-one-record-while-i-have-many-records)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quote here *wildplasser* comment to the question which actually resolved this issue.

> Don't put the return i; inside the loop. See [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) for returning
>   sets and sets of rows.